# Terminal Server (Windows 2008 R2) Performance Tuning for Multimedia

Tags: terminal-server, video

I have a client who's interested in serving embedded videos (Flash/FLV) in their internal SharePoint portal to the thin client users on the Terminal Server.  I suspect that the redraw rate is going to be slow, just as any "heavy" website like Yahoo or MSN is right now for thin client/Terminal Server users.

Question is, where is the bottleneck?  Is it the GPU of the thin client, the Terminal Server, or a combination of both?  I've ruled out network performance: there's CAT5e or CAT6 throughout the building with good high-quality 10/100/1000 switches and there's no performance issues for any of the workstations, just the thin client/Terminal Server users.  The Terminal Server is running on Hyper-V with 8GB of RAM allocated, but even after-hours, with no other sessions, animated rendering/playback over RDP seems slow.

Comment: do you run the ts as a guest so that its easy to clone or what?  Or is this just some kind of test rig. Otherwise this will run poorly no matter what. you may want to look at something like remotefx to make things better but I still wouldn't virtualize a ts server. also is that 8gb allocated to the guest or the host?  how many proc's?

Comment: There's a physical TS as well, 8GB RAM, dual processor; same issue with performance -- I'm starting to think that it's the protocol (RDP) itself not being able to transmit "frames" (whatever the parlance is) fast enough to the client to keep up, but this is just a guess.  I'll look into remotefx.

Comment: @tony roth: looks like RemoteFX is the way to go.  Put your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Upgrade to 2012 R2 - tons was changed in remote desktop (also on protocol level) to facilitate scenarios like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using remotefx if possible.